# $http not injected into controller in a component after minification of JS file

Tags: angularjs, minify, angularjs-components

```
angular.module("datasView",[])
.component("datasView",{
    templateUrl : 'dataview/datasview.template.html',
    controller : function control($http){
        var self = this;
        $http.get('src/data/issues.json').then(function(response){
            // console.log(response.data[0].closed_timestamp);
            self.issueinfo = response.data;
            for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                if(self.issueinfo[i].closed_timestamp == ""){
                    self.issueinfo[i].closed_timestamp = "Open";
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is my code. When I minify this js file, the $http in the argument gets converted to some other random variable and hence does not fetch data from the local json file. How do I rectify this, as it is for a project and minification is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[]` in controller definition as well as `'$http'`

```
controller : [ '$http',function control($http){ 

}]
```

**Full example**

```
angular.module("datasView",[])
.component("datasView",{
    templateUrl : 'dataview/datasview.template.html',
    controller : [ '$http',function control($http){ //opening => [
        var self = this;
        $http.get('src/data/issues.json').then(function(response){
            // console.log(response.data[0].closed_timestamp);
            self.issueinfo = response.data;
            for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                if(self.issueinfo[i].closed_timestamp == ""){
                    self.issueinfo[i].closed_timestamp = "Open";
                }
            }
        });
    }]//closing => ]
});
```

You can read about it here [Declaring AngularJS Modules For Minification](https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification)

Comment: That is correct. The reason is that strings are untouched during the minify process, and that's why declaring the name of the service for the injector: '$http' will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

another way of dependency injection is *$injector propert annotation* (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation):

```
(function (angular) {

  'use strict';

  angular.module("datasView",[]).component('datasView', {
    templateUrl : 'dataview/datasview.template.html',
    controller : controllerFunction
  });

  controllerFunction.$inject = ['$http'];
  function controllerFunction ($http) {
    var self = this;
    $http.get('src/data/issues.json').then(function(response){
        // console.log(response.data[0].closed_timestamp);
        self.issueinfo = response.data;
        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
            if(self.issueinfo[i].closed_timestamp == ""){
                self.issueinfo[i].closed_timestamp = "Open";
            }
        }
    });
  }
```

});

})(angular);